# Should I edit this question to add more clarity or would it be changing the scope?

Tags: discussion

When I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71264/writing-system-of-blind-sea-dwelling-sentients) I was looking for somewhat specific and technical answers (especially relating to what exact materials would be used to write with and where they would be gotten from). While very interesting, the answers I did receive only provided general ideas and insight.

Since I haven't recieved an answer that fully met my needs yet I'm considering putting a bounty on it after editing the question to make it clear of what exactly I am expecting from an answer.

**So should I do the above, or would it be changing the scope of the question meaning I should better start an entirely new question?**

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you can edit away as long as you don't invalidate any of the given answers or change the base of it too much (it's useless to write an answer to the question "I wanna know A", then later come back and see "Edit, skip A, I'd rather know B"). If you want to add "please focus more on tools and materials", then I'd argue that it is okay since the question already states "what would they use to write, write on?"

I haven't tested to put up any bounties yet, but it appears as if you can write a custom text to why you offer the bounty. If you want to bring more attention to the materials, then you might not need to edit your question that much, just give the bounty the explanation "not enough attention to materials".